# Is the following theory consistent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Suppose, we have a  first-order logic theory over a signature {=, $\times$} (where $\times$ is a binary function symbol, and = is the equality symbol), that contains following axioms:
$$\forall x \forall y ( x \times (y \times y) = (x \times y) \times y)$$
$$\exists o \forall x (x \times o = o)$$
$$\exists e \forall x (x \times e = x)$$
$$\forall x \forall y \exists z (x \times z = y)$$
$$\exists x \exists y (\neg(x = y))$$
Is this theory consistent?

It is quite easy to prove that if it is, then every its model has to be infinite. Also, it is quite obvious that the following statements are logically implied by this theory:
$$\neg \forall x \forall y ((y \times y) \times x = y \times(y \times x))$$
$$\neg \exists a \forall x (a \times x = a)$$
$$\neg \forall x \forall y \exists z (z \times x = y)$$
$$\neg \forall x \forall y (x \times y = y \times x)$$

However, I do not know how to proceed further…

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your last two rules are built into the semantics of first-order logic: "$=$" is a logical symbol, which always corresponds to actual equality. (Very old textbooks sometimes don't assume this, but modern sources do.)

Comment: How about the standard interpretation? If that is a model, then the theory is consistent.

Comment: @Noah Schweber, Thank You! I will now edit the question to delete redundant axioms...

Comment: @Bram28, may I ask, what do You mean by standard interpretation? As for myself, I failed to build any model of that theory, despite I honestly tried to do so...

Comment: @YaniorWeg Sorry, I was reminded of the Peano axioms, but of course these are not the Peano axioms, so I shouldn't say 'standard interpretation' ... but still, how about taking numbers (whole, rational, reals?) as the domain, and interpreting $\times$ as multiplication?

Comment: @Bram28, Thank You, but those interpretations do not seem to be models, as 0 in them violates the fourth axiom (one can not divide by it).

Comment: I think you left out an axiom asserting the existence of at least two elements - otherwise, the one-element structure satisfies those axioms.

Comment: @Bram28 In fact, note that "$\times$" can't be commutative (once we rule out the one-element structure via an additional axiom): if it were, taking $x=o$ and $y\not=o$ (where $o$ is some element satisfying rule $2$) would violate rule $4$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Thank You! I have corrected my mistake, by adding the fifth axiom to the theory.

Comment: @YaniorWeg Ah, right, I read that fifth axiom the wrong way ... :P

Comment: Hint: (n.b., I haven't worked out the answer. This is just a hint.) Take axioms 2 and 3 as definitions of constants $o$ (a right annihilator) and $e$ (a right identity) and think about the submodel generated by $o$ and $e$. Axioms 2 and 3 imply that in a model with at least two elements (as required by axiom 5) $o \neq e$. Are the other axioms consistent with $o \neq e$?

Comment: @RobArthan Because of axiom 3, I'm not sure there *is* a nice notion of "substructure generated by." Also, is there an obvious reason why "the" right annihilator and identity have to be unique?

Comment: @YaniorWeg Out of curiosity, how did this particular theory come up?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I don't see any problem with the notion of "substructure generated by $o$ and $e$, but I did write "submodel" and that is more problematic. It's the substructure we need to investigate.  As for the distinctness of  $o$ and $e$, if $o = e$ then axioms 2 and 3 give you that $\forall x (x = o)$.

Comment: @RobArthan Ah, yes, I interpreted "substructure" as "submodel" - my mistake. That said, you misread my other question: I wasn't asking why $o$ and $e$ need to be *distinct* if there is to be more than one element, I asked why they need to be *unique*: why is there only one right annihilator and only one right identity?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I don't understand your concern about the uniqueness.

Comment: @RobArthan It's not really a "concern" per se, but strictly speaking your initial comment "Take axioms 2 and 3 as definitions of constants $o$ (a right annihilator) and $e$ (a right identity)" doesn't really parse if multiple objects satisfy those properties. Of course this isn't a serious worry, since we just pick *some* right annihilator and *some* right identity and look at the substructure they generate, but it is technically an issue with what you said. Also, it's a relevant question in and of itself.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: my statement **parses** fine but doesn't meet the standards that are often applied to what constitutes a definition. (However, the definitional principle I am applying is a perfectly good conservative extension principle unless you reject AC in the metalanguage.) I agree that it's an interesting mathematical question whether $o$ and $e$ are uniquely determined by the axioms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your theory is consistent. Here is a model. I will write $*$ instead of $\times$ because it's easier to type.

The universe is the set $\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ of all nonnegative integers; $x*1=x$ for all $x;$ for $y\ne1$ we define
$$x*y=\begin{cases}
\ \ \ y\ \ \ \ \ \text{ if }\ x=y,\\
\lfloor y/2\rfloor\ \text{ if }\ x\ne y.
\end{cases}$$

Clearly $x*1=x$ and $x*0=0$ for all $x.$

Given $x$ and $y,$ we can find $z$ such that $x*z=y;$ namely, if $y=0$ take $z=0;$ if $y\ne0$ choose $z\in\{2y,2y+1\}$ so that $z\ne x.$

To verify $x*(y*y)=(x*y)*y$ we consider three cases:

If $y=1$ then $x*(y*y)=x*(1*1)=x*1=x$ and $(x*y)*y=(x*1)*1=x*1=x.$

If $x=y$ then $x*(y*y)=y*(y*y)=y*y=y$ and $(x*y)*y=(y*y)*y=y*y=y.$

If $y\ne1$ and $x\ne y$ then $x*(y*y)=x*y=\lfloor y/2\rfloor$ and $(x*y)*y=\lfloor y/2\rfloor*y=\lfloor y/2\rfloor.$